# Compiling a latex document from PHP

Tags: php, latex

I want to use the shell_exec command to compile a very simple latex file in order to generate a report of sorts in the webpage.

I move to the folder where I created the tex file. If I issue the command (from console, by typing)

```
pdflatex report.tex
```

Everything works as expected.

The first thing I have tried is issuing the command in php:

```
$cmd_out = shell_exec("pdflatex " . $wcopy);
```

where $wcopy contains the full path of the file to be compiled (report.tex in the example). The latex file contained an image and at first the compilation failed because I was issuing the pdflatex command from the directory where the php script resides and both the picture and the report.tex files are in a different directory. I fixed that problem by modifying the latex file so that the image path is relative the directory where the php script is located.

The next time I tried to run the script I get this very misterious message from pdflatex:

```
pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ecrm1095): Font ecrm1095 at 600 not found
```

I believe this has something to do the php function shell_exec, although I'm not sure.

Can any one tell me what I might be doing wrong? I added the whole bit of the image, because I think it might be a clue.

EDIT:

Adding requested information. The server is running in a Debian Linux Distribution and the user that will execute those commands is www-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is running as part of a web page, presumably?

The problem is probably that your script is running as a different user. I expect it is running as `apache`; and `apache` might well not have the right path configured, or the right Latex setup for finding font directories and the like.

You haven't given much detail as to what system you're running on, but you could try running it as `apache` to see if you can reproduce the error. If this is Linux, then become root, then go into the right directory, and run

```
su - apache pdflatex report.tex
```

to see what happens. To become root, you might be able to use `su` on its own, if you know the root password; or if you're on Ubuntu, try

```
sudo bash
```

to become root (and give it your own password), and then the line I previously suggested to run as `apache`.

Comment: You might be right. I tried to issue the command and www-data and all I got is "This account is currently not available." The command I tried is  su www-data pdflatex /var/www/pruebas/taskadmin/template/report.tex, executed from the same folder as the php script

Comment: Is there a way to set the paths for the www-data user so that I might try the solution. PS: The error is becuase www-data does not have shell access

Comment: Try running it with `sudo -i -u www-data pdflatex report.tex`. Also try without the `-i`.

Comment: OK, we got something. It worked without the -i. Only weird thing is that it could not overwrite any of the existing files and I had to manually enter alternative names. But other than that it worked!!! Then why doesn't it work in PHP?

Comment: Actually It worked now!!! (Just wrote the file in the php script folder and I wans't looking for it there). I used the solution here to make my "fonts visible to the system" (or somehting like that): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/font-installed-compiles-to-dvi-but-fails-compiling-to-pdf-font-at-600-not-fo. I thought it had not worked but obviously it did!!! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I run with similar problem and it was solved by setting $HOME environment variable to /var/www in a shell-script which invoked pdflatex (or I believe any folder writeable to www-data is ok here). See the details on [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289251/mktextfm-fails-when-pdflatex-is-invoked-by-cgi-bin-script-under-www-data-apache/289252#289252).