# Make latex fonts available for all users for a php compilation

Tags: php, latex, pdflatex

I'm having problems with compiling a latex document using PHP shell_exec. I thought I had solved the problem, but alas I did not.

I have asked somthing similar before:

[Compiling a latex document from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119786/compiling-a-latex-document-from-php/26119943?noredirect=1#comment40937047_26119943)

And this answer led to me believe that the problem is simply the fact that the www-data user that executes the php scripts doesn't have access to the right font file.

It seemed that this page had the solution:
[How can I get PHP to compile a LaTeX document if it (www-data) can't get access to the required packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240725/how-can-i-get-php-to-compile-a-latex-document-if-it-www-data-cant-get-access)

What I did is log as root, execute the command and it threw a bunch of text but no error was reported. Then I tried my webpage again, and the font not found error was still there.

Every time I try a compilation I get the error:

```
<inti.pdf, id=1, 533.995pt x 298.11375pt> <use inti.pdf> [1{/var/lib/texmf/font
s/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./inti.pdf>]
(./report.aux) )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ecrm1095): Font ecrm1095 at 600 not found
```

Don't know if the first part of the message is important or not so I copied it anyways (inti.pdf is a picture in the report.tex).

The missingfont.log file has this line:

```
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ecrm1095
```

How can I make the font be seen by the system. Maybe setting a environment variable? Or a Sudo command so that the font will permanently be seen by all users?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a workaround/another clue to the problem. I'm only posting it here so it might help anyone else.

Firs of all, I was wrong. This is not a user permission issue. I changed my server username to my own and I still had the font not found problem.

However I was able to isolate the problem to one of the latex lines.

In particualar it started working correctly as soon as I commented:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The line was inherited from a header I always use, but was not fundamental to the document and hence this managed to solve it.

Comment: I finally got it to work with the commented line as well. I had to install the package cm-super. In case it helps anyone.